# Odd or even value of k in k-NN binary classifiers?

Tags: machine-learning, k-nearest-neighbour

In binary classification problems, it is recommended to use the odd values of *k* in the kNN as it prevents the tie. I am working on a kNN classifier to find the optimal value of *k*. So, I check the model's accuracy, ROC and PR values in 70 different cases in which the value of k is incremented by 1 each time (1 <= k <= 70). It means I am considering both odd and even values for k. At the end I found the optimal value of k to be an even number and not the odd number. My question is whether my approach was correct or should I just check the odd values of k?

Thanks.

Comment: Where are you getting this recommendation? If both options are equally likely (I question that this is the right conclusion, but let’s go with it for now), that would tell me important information.

Comment: @Dave Well, I didn't find that recommendation in any references but from different people suggesting it and their reason is to prevent the situations in which the distance measure returns an equivalent number of frequencies for two classes. But, I personally believe as I am testing 70 different values of k (both odd and even values), if with an even value of k that specific situation happens then it affects the ROC or accuracy and finally my code picks the value of k with the highest ROC or accuracy (depends on the metric preference), so I think my approach seems to be correct.

Comment: @Dave My other point is that no one can guarantee that with even values of k the tie will happen so the question is when we are not sure whether it will happen or not why to exclude the even values of k in our experiment.